# Matplotlib table cell colors are not rendering

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to create a table in matplotlib with varied row colors. The colors I provide to `ax.table()` are not being applied to the cell. I cannot find anything in the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.table.html?highlight=table#matplotlib.axes.Axes.table) that would indicate why. Is this a bug or am I doing something incorrectly?

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(dpi=300)

ax.axis('off')
ax.axis('tight')

even_color='#9CDEF6'
odd_color='#6549DA'

cell_text = [[0.2] * 3, [0.1] * 3, [0.3] * 3]

labels=['Linear Regression', 'Bayesian Ridge', 'MARS']
columns = ['$R^2$', 'MAE', 'RMSE']

cell_colors = [[even_color] * len(columns) if i % 2 == 0 else [odd_color] * len(columns) for i in range(len(cell_text))]

table = ax.table(cellText=cell_text,
                      rowLabels=labels,
                      cellColours = cell_colors,
                      colLabels=columns,
                      loc='best', edges='open', cellLoc='center')
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either you use closed edges as [Polina](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15779325/polina-dyachkova) [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67307171/2749397) or you modify the underlying artist to set the edge line width to zero:

```
table = ax.table(cellText=cell_text,
                      rowLabels=labels,
                      cellColours = cell_colors,
                      colLabels=columns,
                      loc='best', edges='closed', cellLoc='center')
for c in table.properties()['celld'].values():
    c.set(linewidth=0)
```

And you get a table without cell borders

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If it is okey for you, try to use closed `edges`.

```
table = ax.table(cellText = cell_text,
                 rowLabels = labels,
                 cellColours = cell_colors,
                 colLabels = columns,
                 loc = 'best', edges = 'closed', cellLoc = 'center')
```

I hope it will be useful. [image]